# How can I disable page curl shadown from PageController Application?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I'm having a `PageController` app like a folder and some `ViewControllers` are smaller than screen size and with self.view having a transparent background colour.

Is there a way I can disable the page shadow from the bottom image because it looks ugly in my case?

[image]

Comment: Have you figure out a solution after three years? I am facing the same issue. A walk-around is use a smaller size of PageController, and let ViewControllers be full size of  PageController then the shadow will match the page. But yes, the shadow still there.

Comment: Unfortunately not and did not have the chance to work with it anymore

Answer (score 0):

Set Transition Style to scroll from atribute controller

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in pageViewController.gestureRecognizers) {
    if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        recognizer.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: I only want to disable shadow. I want to use Page curl, not scroll, nor not being able to scroll page!